# help me prove or disprove this statement regarding combinatorics/gamma functions

Tags: combinatorics, gamma-function

I have a question about combinatorics/gamma functions. I would like some help with either disproving or proving the following statement:

Given $k\in\mathbb{N}, m_{1},...,m_{n}\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $m_{1}+...+m_{n}=k$ and $a_{1},...,a_{n} $ positive real numbers and $r_{1},...,r_{n}$ also positive real numbers.

*Statement*:

$$\begin{eqnarray}\underset{m_{1}+...+m_{n}=k}{\sum}&\frac{\overset{n}{\underset{i=1}{\prod}}\left(\begin{array}{c}
m_{i}+r_{i}\\
m_{i}\end{array}\right)a_{i}^{m_{i}}}{\left(\begin{array}{c}
\underset{i=1}{\overset{n}{\sum}}r_{i}+k-1\\
k\end{array}\right)}=\frac{\left(a_{1}r_{1}+...+a_{n}r_{n}\right)^{k}}{\left(\underset{i=1}{\overset{n}{\sum}}r_{i}\right)^{k}},
\end{eqnarray}$$
where the sum is taken over all natural numbers such that $m_{1} + ... + m_{n}=k$.

Comment: Where did this come from? Is it part of some more extensive development of combinatorial identities? Seeing the context may help someone to approach the result.

Answer (score 4):

This statement is false.  For example, if $k=2$ and $n=1$, it becomes
$$
\frac{{r_1+2 \choose 2}a_1^2}{{r_1+1 \choose 2}}=\frac{(a_1 r_1)^2}{r_1^2},
$$
which is never true if $a_1$ and $r_1$ are positive real.

If you take the right-hand side of the proposed statement and expand it as a sum of monomials $C_{(m_1,\ldots,m_n)} \prod_i a_i^{m_i}$, you get
$$
\sum_{m_1+\cdots+m_n=k} \frac{{k\choose m_1\ \cdots\ m_n}\prod_i r_i^{m_i}}{(\sum_i r_i)^k}\prod_i {a_i}^{m_i}=\frac{(\sum_i a_i r_i)^k}{(\sum_i r_i)^k}.
$$
This is similar to the proposed statement, but contains ordinary powers of the $r_i$'s and of $\sum_i r_i$ instead of rising powers.